# Referencing a polygon layer in the field calculator of a point layer to make a virtual field

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, spatialite, point-in-polygon

I have a polygon layer that shows the counties of England and a point layer of project sites. I am trying to make a new virtual field within the point layer that will reference the county that it is in. It needs to be able to stay in the attribute table of the point layer (and not creating a new joined layer) as it will be updated by adding more project sites/points in the future and am working in spatialite where this point shapefile has a join to a records table.

Does anyone know the expression I can use to do this?

Comment: If you install the **refFunctions** plugin which adds extra functionality to the field calculator, you could use the expression `geomwithin( 'nameOfPolygonLayer', 'countyField' )` which retrieves the target field value from the target layer when source feature is within target feature.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try! How do you add a plugin into the field calculator?

Comment: From the menubar at the top, go to `Plugins > Manage and Install plugins`. Then search for the plugin and click the `Install Plugin` button.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried it and it created a new column in the attribute table but all the values are NULL?

Comment: Did you ensure the virtual field is a `string` type? Are both your layers in the same CRS?

Comment: Yes, it was string. The county shapefile is an open source data one and has a different CRS now that I have checked. If I change it to BNG (which is what my project is using) then the polygons disappear.

Comment: You would need to re-save your county shapefile and select the same CRS as your project. You can't use the `Set Layer CRS` option for this as the data will need to be reprojected.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much

Comment: Most welcome, glad it helped! Will summarise the comments as an answer for the convenience of others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you install the **refFunctions** plugin (from the menubar: `Plugins > Manage and Install plugins`) which adds extra functionality to the field calculator, you could use the expression:

```
geomwithin( 'nameOfPolygonLayer', 'countyField' )
```

which retrieves the target field value from the target layer when source feature is within target feature. Ensure both your layers are in the same CRS.